# Sails JS Publish Update Not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

Writing a simple call tracker with sails js and twilio node but publishUpdate doesn't seem to be sending out messages to my frontend clients. Model.publish IS working but Model.publishUpdate is not.   Am I doing any thing obviously wrong or is there something I'm misisng?

Here is my code. 
In my primary controller, I have a specific route to subscribe clients to my Model

in MainController.js

```
calls: function(req,res){
            Calls.find(function foundCalls(err, calls) {
                    if (err) return next(err);

                    // subscribe this socket to the Calls classroom
                    Calls.subscribe(req.socket);

                    // subscribe this socket to the Calls instance rooms
                    Calls.subscribe(req.socket, calls);

                    // This will avoid a warning from the socket for trying to render
                    // html over the socket.
                    res.send(calls,200);
            });
    },
```

In my app.js file I have

```
socket.on('connect', function socketConnected() {

    socket.get('/main/calls', function(response){console.log(response)});


    socket.on('message', function(message) {
            console.log(message);
    });
});
```

In another controller I have this:
CallController.js

```
   takecall: function(req,res) {

      Calls.findOneByCallSid(req.body.CallSid).done(function(err, thiscall) {
                    if(err){
                            return next(err);

                   } else {
                            // 1a. Save additional parameters
                            thiscall.DialCallDuration=req.body.DialCallDuration
                            thiscall.DialCallSid=req.body.DialCallSid
                            thiscall.RecordingUrl=req.body.RecordingUrl
                            thiscall.DialCallStatus=req.body.DialCallStatus
                            thiscall.RecordingDuration=req.body.RecordingDuration
                            thiscall.RecordingSid=req.body.RecordingSid
                            thiscall.save(function(err,call) {
                                    if (err) return next(err);
                                    console.log(call.id);
                                    Calls.publishUpdate(call.id,{message:'hello'});
                            });

                            // 3. Display twiml that tells twilio we are done with call workflow
                            var twilio = require('twilio');
                            var resp = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
                            res.send(resp.toString(), 200);
                    }
            });



    }
```

Comment: What version of Sails are you running?